# 管理者権限によって公開サイトの処理を分けたい

Tags: wordpress

管理者権限でWordPress管理画面にログインしている状態で、公開サイトを開いたとき、一般ユーザーと表示する項目を分けたいと考えています。

公開サイト側でwp_get_current_userを使い、ユーザー情報の取得を試みましたが、ユーザー情報が取得できませんでした。
管理画面にログインした状態で、同じブラウザで閲覧していますが、公開サイト側で取得できない状況です。

管理画面でダンプするとユーザー情報が出ているのですが、公開サイト側に引き継がれないのでしょうか？

また、管理者かどうかを判定し、処理を振り分ける方法をご存知の方おられましたら、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

使用しているテーマは、「storefront」です。
https://ja.wordpress.org/themes/storefront/

```
wp_get_current_user()

object(WP_User)#9332 (8) {
  ["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#9345 (0) {
  }
  ["ID"]=>
  int(0)
  ["caps"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["cap_key"]=>
  NULL
  ["roles"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["allcaps"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["filter"]=>
  NULL
  ["site_id":"WP_User":private]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

”公開サイト側”がインストールしているwordpressのルートなら、(見当はずれならごめんなさい)
見ている内容が違うような。　テーマのindex.php先頭に以下のコードを入れるとログインしているユーザ情報が表示されると思います。

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    print_r(wp_get_current_user());
    exit;
}
```

追伸、`require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php';` とかでwordpressディレクトリ外でget_posts関数などを呼び出している場合は、ユーザ情報は読み出せません。

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'hoge_login', 10, 2 );
```

を使用してcookieなどに、ハッシュ化したlogin情報をセットするしかないと思います。